# Video resolution on webpage

Tags: flash, web

I have flash video files to display on to website.The flv files are in 1024*768 size.But , when i am displaying the flv on website with 960*720,the video quality is not good.

How can we handle the video sizes on webpage?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll generally want to display video at its native resolution. Scaled video looks poor, requires more processor time, and scaling down is a waste of stream bits. Re-encode the FLV from its source for each target resolution; most encoders have a much better scaler built-in than the player can manage.

Either way, 960x720 is an ambitious resolution for Flash Video. Many users won't have the power to play it back smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

You have a 1024x768 video file and it looks bad in 960x720? That sounds like the encoding took away much of the quality of the original footage. You would have to check your FLV encoder's settings for resolution / bitrate / whatever else the codec provides for.